# Custom Search Query running on every page

Tags: search

I have a custom search query which I have put in a plugin. The homepage has a custom search form and when the user searches for something, it goes to the search page and displays the result.

My issue is that the custom query runs on every page of the website, even in the admin panel. It keeps throwing the error `latitude and longitude not defined` on every page.

I have used `is_search()` function to make sure the function runs only on search pages but it doesn't work. It still runs the query!

This is the code:

```
        /**
         * Custom Search on Homepage
         *
         * 
         */
        add_filter('posts_fields', 'distance_query'); 
        add_filter('posts_where', 'lat_lng_define');
        add_filter('posts_join', 'lat_lng_join');
        add_filter('posts_groupby', 'having_distance');
        add_filter('posts_orderby', 'sort_distance');

        /**
         * The Fields
         *
         * 
         */
        function distance_query( $fields ) {
            global $wpdb;

            //if(isset($_GET['latitude'] )|| isset($_GET['longitude'] )) {
                $lat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['latitude'] );
                $lng = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['longitude'] );
            //} else {
            //  return;
            //}


           if (is_search())

               $fields .= ", 
           SOME QUERY"

            return $fields;
          }

/**
 * The Join
 *
 * 
 */
  function lat_lng_join( $join) {
    global $wpdb;
if (is_search())
     $join = " QUERY";
    return $join;
  }


    //Likewise the rest of the query
```

If I isset the $GET values, the homepage shows 404:

```
 if(isset($_GET['latitude'] )|| isset($_GET['longitude'] )) {
            $lat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['latitude'] );
            $lng = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['longitude'] );
        } else {
          return;
        }
```

The search query running on every page is making my website too slow. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you place the `$lat` and `$lng` within the `is_search()` conditional?

Comment: @czerspalace I get a 404 on homepage

Comment: As it is, you have a syntax error in your conditional. You are missing the curly brackets `{}` so the query is modified regardless of the if statement. If this is not a copy/paste error, try to put `if( is_search() ) { $fields = ...; return $fields  }` same thing with your `$join` variable.

Comment: @bynicolas it may be bad practice to not use curly brackets but it's not a syntax error. It should work with or without it. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets

Comment: No it won't... Did you read the answer correctly?  If you have more than one statement in your if, it **will** *break in funny ways* to paraphrase the answer you linked to. And guess what, your code is breaking in funny ways ! So while technically not a *syntax error*, the syntax **is wrong** in  the way you are using it. An `if` without the `{}` will consider **ONLY** the **next** statement as part of the condition.

Comment: @bynicolas, thanks for pointing out. I feel stupid now. This was it. Can you please post your comment as answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working, good luck with project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the curly brackets `{}` around your query statements so the query is modified regardless of the `if` statement.

So try modifying your code to have something like

```
if( is_search() ) { 
  $fields = '...'; 
  return $fields 
}
```

same thing with your `$join` variable

Remember that while using `if` without brackets is acceptable for single statements, it is better to always use the curly brackets. Even if it's only to make the code more consistent and easy to read for another coder (or even you in 6 months from now).

You'll save an awful lot of time debugging errors that aren't actually ones.  A little bit like you just experienced with your issue here :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding more conditional checks as required.

```
if ( is_search() && ! is_admin && ! is_front_page() && ! is_page() ) {

   $fields .= "SOME QUERY";

  return $fields;
}
```